# My DIV width is not expanding with the size of its children

Tags: css, html, width

I have a parent div (nav) that is 1000px.  Within that there is a child div (nav-drop-panel), and within that one another child (drop-panel-col).  Basically, the drop-panel-col is a list of links in navigation.  As there is a specific height, I can only add so many links before adding another column (so there's 1-4 drop-panel-col divs within nav-drop-panel).

I want the nav-drop-panel div to size itself according to the number of columns within it.  So if there's only one, it's smaller than if there's 4.  It will never exceed or even come close to the 1000px width of its parent div (nav).  For some reason, if I don't set nav-drop-panel to a specific width (which makes it too big for one column), it assigns itself an arbitrary width and all of my columns are pushed down and it looks terrible.

I've tried a few solutions to other related questions from here, but nothing has worked so far.

My HTML:

```
<div class="nav-drop-panel">
    <div class="drop-panel-col">
        <a class="cat">Vehicle Graphics</a>
        <a href="/info_truck_graphics.php">Pick-Up Truck</a>
        <a href="/info_van_lettering.php">Van</a>
        <a href="/info_trailer_graphics.php">Enclosed Trailer</a>
        <a href="/info_commercial_truck_graphics.php">Box Truck</a>
        <a href="/info_suv_graphics.php">SUV</a>
        <a href="/car-lettering.php">Car</a>
        <a href="/info_boat_graphics.php">Boat</a>
        <a href="/info_bus_graphics.php">Bus</a>
        <a href="/custom-signs/magnetic-car-signs-vehicle-magnet-sign/">ScratchGuard&#153; Magnets</a>
        <a href="/info_vinyl_Letters.php">Vinyl Lettering and Graphics</a>
        <p></p>     
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
#nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 15;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    /* position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px; */
}
#nav .nav-drop-panel {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-right: 3px solid #BBBBBB;
    height: 431px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-top: 19px;
    /* position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 218px; */
}

#nav .drop-panel-col {
    color: #333333;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

#nav .drop-panel-col a{
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 202px;
}
```

Greatly appreciate any help or ideas, thanks. :)

EDIT: Just showing what I did to remove the positioning. I had just commented it out to see if it would at least expand, and work from there.

Comment: Maybe someone else will understand this better off the bat, but for me setting up a jsfiddle would do worlds of good towards understanding your issue.

Comment: @anubis , it's been several weeks since I gave you my answer, does it not do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely-positioned elements are **no longer part of the layout**. The parent element has no idea where, or how large they are.

You need to use JavaScript to calculate all of this an adjust the size of the parent accordingly... or use a layout that doesn't use absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I removed the absolute positioning on both divs just to see if it would help, but the div is still not expanding horizontally.  I'll keep trying, though.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to .nav-drop-panel [seemed to do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/2M2VN/5/); I've also reduced the printed code slightly(`margin-left`, `margin-top`, etc reduced to `margin: etc etc etc etc;`).  To see your unaltered, but working(as in just with the `display: inline-block;` added) version, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMDjH/1/).